# Alt-Tab works only for the current active application on 14.04 gnome+metacity

Tags: 14.04, gnome, shortcut-keys, metacity

I've just installed a fresh `14.04`, I use Gnome with metacity, (after trying Compiz...) but I can't get the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keyboard to have the standard behaviour. When I use it, it only displays the windows of a given application, fox example if I have 3 Firefox opened windows, but all the other applications are ignored and not included.

Before using metacity I tried modifying several Compiz settings, I am wondering if it can be related.

Moreover, when trying to access the metacity options, `gconf-editor /apps/metacity`, the path is not found `/apps/metacity` there is nothing at all.

[image]

And I can't find the short-cut in the keyboard settings:

[image]

*Edit 7/8*: I Have found that <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> does exactly what I want, but I can't find it in the keyborad shortcuts.. how can I modify it?

Comment: a screenshot would be helpful here (Alt+Tab window)

Comment: @ElefantPhace Added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to myself, I finally managed to change the shortcuts using the `dconf-editor`, the shortcuts are stored in the key folder: `org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings`.